# Unusable 20.04.2.0 system following power outage

Tags: command-line

I am a new user of Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS version. Yesterday, I have installed it in my PC. At the time of using Ubuntu, the electricity has gone. And I am facing now the problem. Ubuntu Desktop is coming but all is blue, without Firefox any software is not opening. And the terminal is not opening also.

Now what should I do now please help me.

Comment: Sounds like the only option is to reinstall. Lucky it's a brand new install!

Comment: Since you are a new user, you likely still have your installer media handy. Find it, boot from it, and enter the "Try Ubuntu" environment. Backup your data. Then run a filesytem check ("fsck" -- look it up) on your installed system. If it successfully repairs your installed system, you are done. If the filesystem cannot be repaired, then reinstall (that's why you backed up your data). If you are in a location with frequent power loss, use the Search box at the top of the page for strategies to minimize filesystem corruption when the mains go dark. There. You've been helped.

Comment: FYI:  You can run `fsck` from a number of GUI tools too, eg. `gnome-disks`, or `gparted` etc... but be sure it's your installed system (and not the *live* media you are running from) you `fsck`